# How to execute system command with unknown arguments?

Tags: go

I have a bunch of systems commands which are somwhat similar to appending new content to a file. I wrote a simple script to execute system commands, which works well if there are single words like 'ls' , 'date' etc. But if the command is greater than that, program dies.

The following is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
)

func exe_cmd(cmd string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Println(cmd)
    c = cmd.Str
    out, err := exec.Command(cmd).Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error occured")
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", out)
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(3)

    x := []string{"echo newline >> foo.o", "echo newline >> f1.o", "echo newline >> f2.o"}
    go exe_cmd(x[0], wg)
    go exe_cmd(x[1], wg)
    go exe_cmd(x[2], wg)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

The following is the error i see

```
exec: "echo newline >> foo.o": executable file not found in $PATHexec: 
"echo newline >> f2.o": executable file not found in $PATHexec: 
"echo newline >> f1.o": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I guess, this may be due to, not sending cmds and arguments seperately ( http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command ). I am wondering how to subvert this, since I don't know how many arguments will be there in my command which needs to be executed.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I found a relatively decent way to achieve the same .

```golang
out, err := exec.Command("sh","-c",cmd).Output()
```

Works for me until now. Still finding better ways to achieve the same.

Edit1:

Finally a easier and efficient (atleast so far) way to do would be like this

```
func exeCmd(cmd string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
  fmt.Println("command is ",cmd)
  // splitting head => g++ parts => rest of the command
  parts := strings.Fields(cmd)
  head := parts[0]
  parts = parts[1:len(parts)]

  out, err := exec.Command(head,parts...).Output()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s", err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%s", out)
  wg.Done() // Need to signal to waitgroup that this goroutine is done
}
```

Thanks to  variadic arguments in go and people that pointed that out to me :)

Comment: it works fine for the string mentioned in problem. But if you try to execute something like "echo new >> test.txt" it breaks. :(

Comment: If you want to do commands with multiple parts like "command1 && command2" then the first (pre-ediut) method works, even though the second fails.

Comment: I think it will fail on cases like `date +"%y %m %d"`

Comment: For Windows the equivalent is `cmd := exec.Command("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c", command)`. You should probably use `exec.LookPath` to get the system's shell path from `$PATH`/`%PATH%`.

Answer (score 11):

For `exec.Command()` the first argument needs to be the path to the executable. Then the remaining arguments will be supplied as arguments to the executable. Use `strings.Fields()` to help split the word into a []string.

### Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "strings"
)

func exe_cmd(cmd string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Println(cmd)
            parts := strings.Fields(cmd)
    out, err := exec.Command(parts[0],parts[1]).Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error occured")
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", out)
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    commands := []string{"echo newline >> foo.o", "echo newline >> f1.o", "echo newline >> f2.o"}
    for _, str := range commands {
        wg.Add(1)
        go exe_cmd(str, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Here's an alternative approach that just writes all the commands to a file then executes that file within the context of the new created output directory.

### Example 2

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "path/filepath"
)
var (
    output_path = filepath.Join("./output")
    bash_script = filepath.Join( "_script.sh" )
)
func checkError( e error){
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
func exe_cmd(cmds []string) {
    os.RemoveAll(output_path)
    err := os.MkdirAll( output_path, os.ModePerm|os.ModeDir )
    checkError(err)
    file, err := os.Create( filepath.Join(output_path, bash_script))
    checkError(err)
    defer file.Close()
    file.WriteString("#!/bin/sh\n")
    file.WriteString( strings.Join(cmds, "\n"))
    err = os.Chdir(output_path)
    checkError(err)
    out, err := exec.Command("sh", bash_script).Output()
    checkError(err)
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}

func main() {
    commands := []string{
    "echo newline >> foo.o",
    "echo newline >> f1.o",
    "echo newline >> f2.o",
    }
   exe_cmd(commands)
}
```

Comment: its executing it. but not in real sense. the file should have the newline appeneded to it. But it aint happening.

Comment: I think it would be better if you wrote the commands to a bash script, then used go to execute the script. Otherwise you're going to have to add support for standard input and output.

Comment: hmm. thats nice. But it will be nice to have if I could somehow truncate the string and send the []string elements are a parameter to Command() . That will obviate the need of doing all these.

Comment: Rahul, I believe what you are referring to is a Variadic value. e.g:

exec.Command("ls", args...).Output()

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

Comment: small correction: the second argument of `Command` should be `parts[1:]...`, otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 8):

```
    out, _ := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z\"").Output()
    exec.Command("sh","-c","ls -al -t | grep go >>test.txt").Output()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n\n",out)
```

Tested couple cases and all work good. This is a lifesaver if you are dealing with quick shell commands in your program. Not tested with complex cases.

Comment: This saved many hours of my life. Thank you!