# Os Exec Sudo Command in Go

Tags: go

In the process of familiarizing myself with Go and goroutines I have hit a road block with executing commands. The format of these commands are:

```
sudo find /folder -type f | while read i; do sudo -S chmod 644 "$i"; done
```

With code taken from [How to execute system command in Golang with unknown arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437336/how-to-execute-system-command-in-golang-with-unknown-arguments) I'm trying to execute this command but I believe it's not executing due to the first argument being sudo, I could be wrong.  I have just two questions.

When these commands fail to run I am returned "exit status 1", is there a way to get a more detailed error than what I am doing? Question two, why would I be getting "exit status 1" with this script? What is going on that isn't supposed to?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func ExeCmd(cmd string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    parts := strings.Fields(cmd)
    head := parts[0]
    // Head at this point is "sudo"
    parts = parts[1:len(parts)]
    out, err := exec.Command(head,parts...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
    wg.Done() // Signal to WaitGroup goroutine finished
}

func InArray(a []string, e string) bool {
    for _, x := range a {
        if x == e {
            return true
            fmt.Print("True")
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    exec.Command("sudo ls > /dev/null") // Get sudo password just once, doesn't seem to work with Go
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fdbslices := []string{"f", "d", "b", "files", "directories", "both"}
    commands := []string{}
    fdb := ""
    filep := ""
    dirp := ""

    // Grab Path
    fmt.Print("Path: ")
    findpath, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    findpath = strings.ToLower(strings.Trim(findpath, "\n"))

    // Grab Files, Directories, or Both
    for {
        fmt.Print("Files, Directories, or Both: ")
        fdb, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
        fdb = strings.ToLower(strings.Trim(fdb, "\n"))
        if InArray(fdbslices, fdb) == true { break }
    }

    // Build commands string, these come out as they should
    for {
        if fdb == "f" || fdb == "files" {
            fmt.Print("Permissions for Files: ")
            filep, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
            filep = strings.Trim(filep, "\n")
            commands = append(commands, "sudo find " + findpath + " -type f | while read i; do sudo -S chmod " + filep + " \"$i\"; done")
        }
        if fdb == "d" || fdb == "directories" {
            fmt.Print("Permissions for Directories: ")
            dirp, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
            dirp = strings.Trim(dirp, "\n")
            commands = append(commands, "sudo find " + findpath + " -type d | while read i; do sudo -S chmod " + dirp + " \"$i\"; done")
        }
        if fdb == "b" || fdb == "both" {
            fmt.Print("Permissions for Files: ")
            filep, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
            filep = strings.Trim(filep, "\n")
            commands = append(commands, "sudo find " + findpath + " -type f | while read i; do sudo -S chmod " + filep + " \"$i\"; done")
            fmt.Print("Permissions for Directories: ")
            dirp, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
            dirp = strings.Trim(dirp, "\n")
            commands = append(commands, "sudo find " + findpath + " -type d | while read i; do sudo -S chmod " + dirp + " \"$i\"; done")
        }
        break
    }

    // Execute Commands
    for _, str := range commands {
        wg.Add(1)
        fmt.Print("Doing: " + str + "\r\n")
        go ExeCmd(str, wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Example Terminal output:

```
Path: test
Files, Directories, or Both: b
Permissions for Files: 644
Permissions for Directories: 755
Doing: find test -type f | while read i; do sudo -S chmod 644 "$i"; done
Doing: find test -type d | while read i; do sudo -S chmod 755 "$i"; done
exit status 1

exit status 1
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess that if you run your Go program with `sudo` you won't have to put `sudo` in front of your shell command. But that's kind of a workaround then...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`exec.Command()` will ask the kernel to execute the given process directly.  However, the command you are passing is a string of multiple programs hooked together by a shell script.

If you want to execute a shell script, you should use something like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "sudo find ...")
```

Comment: The command you're executing in the sample code is `sudo find somepath -type d | while read i; do sudo -S chmod somedir "$i"; done`.  The kernel knows how to execute the `sudo find somepath -type d`, but it is the shell that hooks up the file descriptors for the `|` operation.  Also, the `while` loop is a shell builtin.

Comment: Using this with /bin/sh -c sudo x it comes up as improper syntax.  Taking out sudo makes it work fine but without sudo.  Would you have any ideas how to incorporate that?

Comment: Are you passing the shell script as a single argument, as shown in the answer?  Don't attempt to word split it.

Comment: Yes, the line now reads:                         out, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", cmd).Output()