# golang linux add an user with help of exec

Tags: go

I want to add an user to my server with golang exec function but its not working I tried multiple things but cant find an working solution.  Is it maybe because of this? "$(openssl passwd -1 Test)"

here is my code

```
    cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "useradd -p", "$(openssl passwd -1 Test)", "Test1234")
    b, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
```

Comment: Separate `useradd` and `-p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec.Command` runs an executable directly. Each string is a literal argument. In your example, `sudo` is the program, and you're passing `useradd -p` as the first argument, then `$(openssl passwd -1 Test)` as the second, etc.

`useradd -p` is it's own command, and won't work as a single string argument.

`$(openssl passwd -1 Test)` is bash (or another shell) specific syntax, which won't work in `exec.Command`.

You're actually trying to run three executables - `sudo`, `useradd`, and `openssl`. You can either run each executable in a separate `exec.Command` call or run a shell directly.

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command("openssl", "passwd", "-1", "Test")
    passwordBytes, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // remove whitespace (possibly a trailing newline)
    password := strings.TrimSpace(string(passwordBytes))
    cmd = exec.Command("useradd", "-p", password, "Test1234")
    b, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
```

(I'd recommend not running `sudo` directly in your go code, as the program you're running should be managing permissions directly.)

To run a shell directly to use the `$(...)` subcommand syntax, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24095983/2178159.

Comment: Hello, its returning useradd: invalid field '$1$Gu9wY7nT$.Tl39zCwvI3.I1bV0rg.b1
'

Comment: That's going to be an issue with your usage of `useradd`. Make sure whatever you're trying to run through go works on the terminal as well. It looks like you need to encrypt the password with `crypt` first, using the `-p` option - https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd.

Comment: But why does it work on the terminal and not in go? When I put ```useradd -p $1$eHZrL9Px$RgxlN19Wu1S/yV8auzDeE/ Test```

It works

Comment: I don't know. Are the `$` characters being expanded by your shell? (does it behave the same if you wrap the password string in single quotes?)

Comment: I got the solution. ```a := strings.TrimSpace(string(password))``` and it worked

Comment: Good idea, there might have been a trailing newline