# Discover shared folders for a given computer?

Tags: go, shared-directory

I'm trying to discover and walk the shared folders and files of a computer on my network, let's call it ComputerA. If I know ComputerA is sharing a folder called Source, I can use

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir("\\\\ComputerA\\Source")
```

to get a list of all the files in Source. However, I can't do this to find Source (or any other shared folders)

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir("\\\\ComputerA")
```

It seems that `ioutil` can't list the root shared folders using a UNC path like this. I've looked over the stock packages rather quickly and nothing else jumps out at me as a way to do this.

It's not a permissions issue as far as I can tell. I can open up explorer and go straight to `\\ComputerA` and it'll work just fine.

How else can I discover the shared folders for a specific computer on my network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't seem directly supported by Go libraries like `ioutil` or `net` or other packages.

Instead that would depend on the file system used, and would best use a system command ([`exec.Command().Output()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20437336/6309) ).
For instance, for Windows, `net share` (for local shares) or [`net view` (for remote shares)](https://superuser.com/a/769694/141).